# Branch.io deep link doesn't return data if user doesn't open newly installed app within 20 minutes

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking, branch.io

Currently we have an Expo managed standalone app and we are using Branch.io's deep links to associate invites. If a user downloads an app through that link and opens the app within 20 minutes, the integration works as expected (data retrieved through branch sdk).

However if a user downloads the app and waits more than 20 minutes, the sdk will no longer retrieve any data.

The default attribution window is supposed to be 120 minutes. We have tried increasing that to 240 minutes, but does not work.